# Word embeddings over user/customer reviews corpus

Tags: nlp, corpus, word2vec

Most of the embeddings, publicly available, that I know are done over news articles, which use a different language/words as the one used in user/customer reviews.

Although such embeddings can be used in NLP tasks concerning reviews
and user generated content, I think the difference in language has an important role, and as such I would rather use embeddings trained over user generated content, such as product reviews.

I'm looking for a corpus of reviews or comments in English -- although in German and Dutch would also be useful -- to generate embeddings, or alternatively embeddings already trained over such a corpus.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "embeddings"?

Comment: Any language modeling and feature learning techniques where words are mapped to vectors of real numbers in a low-dimensional space relative to the vocabulary size, e.g.:  Google's Word2vec or Stanford University's GloVe

Comment: thanks, that makes sense! According to this quote ([source](http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec)) 
*Word2vec creates vectors that are distributed numerical representations of word features, features such as the context of individual words.* 
So these are vectors of word frequencies, collocations, etc? Like a feature matrix, but potentially with different categories mixed together? 
Just trying to understand how they are different from the "standard" vectors of counts, frequencies, that are commonly used in NLP...

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial/presentation](http://www.coling-2014.org/COLING%202014%20Tutorial-fix%20-%20Tomas%20Mikolov.pdf) from Mikolov, the author of word2vec (i.e., CBOW and Skip-Gram models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two datasets/corpus in English:

https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge

https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Amazon.html

in German:

http://www.uni-weimar.de/en/media/chairs/webis/corpora/corpus-webis-cls-10/